# How: Bind to a UserControl's DependencyProperty, when the UserControl has a DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext, dependency-properties

My problem is not wiring up `DependencyProperties` in a `UserControl`. This is not an issue. When I bind a button in a `UserControl` to the `UserControl`'s `DependencyProperty` called `TargetCommand`, the binding breaks when I set a `DataContext` on the `UserControl`. I've tried using `FindAncestor` and of course `ElementName`, but they only function when there is no `DataContext` on the `UserControl`.

Is there a way around this?

example:

Main Window

```
<Window xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace">
    <Grid>
         <UserControls:MyUserControl 
             TargetCommand="{Binding PathToCommand}"
             DataContext="{Binding PathToSomeModel}" />
```

MyUserControl Code Behind

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "TargetCommand", typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MyUserControl ) );

    public ICommand TargetCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue( TargetCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TargetCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
```

MyUserControl - Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="root">
    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TargetCommand}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=TargetCommand, ElementName=root}" />
```

The RelativeSource and ElementName methods of binding in the MyUserControl both wire up correctly as long as the DataContext is not set on MyUserControl in the MainWindow. Neither work once the DataContext is set.

Is there a way to set a DataContext on MyUserControl, and still preserve the DependencyProperty Binding to TargetCommand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is your `PathToCommand` defined at? If I'm reading your example correctly, it should be somewhere higher in the VisualTree than the UserControl. In that case, you'd bind to whatever control has the DataContext containing PathToCommand and bind to `DataContext.PathToCommand`

```
<Window xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace">
    <Grid x:Name="PART_Root">
         <UserControls:MyUserControl 
             TargetCommand="{Binding ElementName=PART_Root, Path=DataContext.PathToCommand}" />
```

Comment: Nice... I overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something here, but why do you need a DependencyProperty here when you are setting a DataContext? Why not have a property in your model that can be bound to directly from the button?

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to attach this command to my model. From my model's perspective.